# Kendoui MVC Multiselect Wrapper no initial values

Tags: c#, razor, kendo-ui, multi-select

Trying to use the Multiselect kendoui widget wrapper.  The server side filtering is working fine but i can't get the initial values to be populated when the widget initializes.  Do you know what i'm doing wrong here?

```
<div class="container-div grid-tab-content-pane">

@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Name(AMultiName)
      .DataTextField("PrettyText")
      .DataValueField("MapAbbreviation")
      .Placeholder("Edit EMR maps...")
      .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
      .MinLength(3)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .HighlightFirst(true)
      .Value(new []
          {
              new {PrettyText = "Abcdef",MapAbbreviation = "s01"},
              new {PrettyText = "2nde obn", MapAbbreviation = "asdf012"}
          })

      .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r=>r.Action("ReadMapOptions","EmrMappingKendo", new {Area="Messaging"})).ServerFiltering(true)).MinLength(3)   
      )
```

BTW i'm using version 2013.2.918.340 of the kendoui dll

Setting autobind to false has no affect.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Name(AMultiName)
      .DataTextField("PrettyText")
      .DataValueField("MapAbbreviation")
      .Placeholder("Edit EMR maps...")
      .AutoBind(true)
      .Value(new []
          {
              new {PrettyText = "Abcdef",MapAbbreviation = "s01"},
              new {PrettyText = "2nde obn", MapAbbreviation = "asdf012"}
          })

      .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r=>r.Action("ReadMapOptions","EmrMappingKendo", new {Area="Messaging"})).ServerFiltering(true)).MinLength(3)   
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason this works.  Not sure why but it does.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Name(AMultiName)
      .DataTextField("PrettyText")
      .DataValueField("MapAbbreviation")
      .Placeholder("Edit EMR maps...")
      .Filter(FilterType.Contains).MinLength(3)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .DataSource(
        ds => ds.Read(r=>r.Action("ReadMapOptions","EmrMappingKendo", new {Area="Messaging"})))
      .Value(new List<EmrMapping>
          {
              new EmrMapping {PrettyText = "Abcdef",MapAbbreviation = "s01"},
              new EmrMapping {PrettyText = "2nde obn", MapAbbreviation = "asdf012"}
          })
      )
```

came across this link which pointed me do [Kendoui docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/multiselect/overview#pre-select-values-on-initial-loading)

Comment: Oh, i am on 2013.1.319, and deferred initialization is supported > 2013.1.514 as your link says. you are right. Upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

`.AutoBind(false)` is the cause, we have to set it `true` to set some value(s) on initialization. Moreover, `.MinLength(3)` may retrict server calls, hope its deliberate.

Comment: Unfortunately .AutoBind has no affect on showing the initial values.  Please see my edit (ive also tried not supplying the property at all, all have the same behavior of not showing the initial values).

Comment: also i do want to restrict the filtering to fire only when >=3 characters are provided, and this seems to be functioning just fine.  The only issue im having is getting the initial values to show.

Comment: cobolstinks: Initialization value(s) must be on the datasource. Are you sure your read action supplying all those value pairs? If your json is good, believe me you have to set `AutoBind = true`, otherwise `undefined` text will be on each options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,auto bind has nothing to do with making multi select values pre selected on page load.

To make multiselect as preselected with the datasource it got bound with,

we need to call one action method which in turn returning a list of type   List items = new List();

and on UI side we need to call like this:

.Value(Model.Getsources)

here Getsources is method in controller returning list of values.